# Update RVM list known

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is it possible to update the list of known rubies (what you get with `rvm list known`) without upgrading the entirety of rvm?

Comment: @sawa reply posted at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6319864#6319864

Comment: I see. Good that you could convince him. Looks like youve been to many places.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No it is not, some of the version changes require changes in code,
 <strike>you should be good with sticking to stable to keep more stability (if that is your concern):</strike>

```
rvm get stable
```

you should be good with sticking to master (as it's stable) to get latest versions:

```
rvm get master
```

Comment: I don't get it: I ran `rvm get stable`, but `ruby-2.2.3` is showing up at the latest, and as of now, `2.3.0` is available.

Answer (score 4):

[mpapis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650963/2767755) answer and opinion is 100% correct. The settings I had in my laptop is below.

Add the the line `rvm_autoupdate_flag=2` to `~/.rvmrc`. It will auto update Rvm, all the time, whenever you will do like `rvm list known`.

**Example:**

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> rvm list known
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.26.0', you are using older version '1.25.33'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
arup@linux-wzza:~> echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
arup@linux-wzza:~> rvm list known
Found old RVM 1.25.33 - updating.
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.0.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.0/1.26.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Wed 29 Oct 2014 06:22:06 PM IST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).
#....................
#.....................
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I needed for RVM v1.29 installed for multi users on Pop!_OS:

```
rvmsudo rvm get stable
```

Comment: Please explain the code you are proposing as solution.