# Installing Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM

Tags: ruby

I have tried installing `Ruby 2.0.0` using `RVM`:

```
  rvm install 2.0.0
```

Once installation is done. I did `rvm list`. It shown like below:

```
rvm rubies

   jruby-1.6.5.1 [ i386 ]
   /home/username/.rvm/scripts/list: line 294: /home/username/.rvm/rubies/rbx-2.0.0/config: No such file or directory
rbx-2.0.0 [  ]
=* ree-1.8.7-2011.12 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Why did it install `Rubinius 2.0-rc1` ?? did anyone face this issue?? Any help??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your rvm is probably not up to date, and by doing so the list of installable rubies also. Rvm probably took the best match, that was Rubinius 2

When you do

```
rvm list known
```

You obtain the [list of known rubies that you can install](https://rvm.io/rubies/list/)

This [list is updated at the same time you update rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650164/update-rvm-list-known). Then you need to update rvm before installing MRI Ruby 2.0.0

```
rvm get stable
```

Comment: I did `rvm get head`. it worked !!. I think `rvm get stable` also works.

Comment: Nice to hear. I can tell you rvm get stable works, I try it this morning.

Comment: @codeit The difference between `head` and `stable` is alluded to [here](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting).  The `head` version is, according to that page, for the "more adventurous."

Comment: I found that the RVM installed by Ubuntu was very broken. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395) resolved all my issued however.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure you have the latest RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

After installing RVM, run the relevant `libyaml` installation for your system:

**Debian-based systems:**

```
apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

**Fedora/CentOS/RHEL systems:**

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

**Mac with Homebrew:**

```
brew install libyaml
```

**Lastly:**

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.0.0 \ 
    --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
    --verify-downloads 1
rvm use 2.0.0
```

Comment: please correct your font size. That way it will be more readable

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
rvm list known
```

You obtain the list of known rubies that you can install

This list is updated at the same time you update rvm. Then you need to update rvm before installing MRI Ruby 2.0.0

Update rvm to the latest version

```
rvm get stable
```

Then try installing ruby

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

if there is any error, such as missing packages, it will be listed. Install those packages for debian-based systems using

Use yum install / brew install  for Fedora/CentOS/RHEL systems , Mac with Homebrew respectively

```
apt-get install "your missing packges"

eg:
sudo apt-get install libsigsegv2 gawk libgdbm-dev libffi-dev
```

once the missing packages are installed.

try installing ruby 2.0.0

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some good instructions at https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq, includes setting up libyaml and openssl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rvm use 2.0.0`.

If it tells you that you have it not installed, you just do:

`rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p598`

It will install everything that you need for you and then you can select which version of Ruby to use with `rvm use`