# RVM and Ruby 2.0.0 under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

When trying to install Ruby using RVM under my Ubuntu 12.04 (with `rvm install 2.0.0`), I get the following:

```
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
```

And it tries to fetch repositories but it doesn't install anything.  Shall I add some repositories or what should I do?

I also have tried running `rvm requirements` but no luck either.

What I get after running rvm install 2.0.0 is:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg [72 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable Release
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
Get:3 http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release.gpg [489 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release [49.6 kB]
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Get:5 http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release [2,603 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en_US
Get:6 http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,148 B]
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources [14 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en_US
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources [13.7 kB]
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources [1,306 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages [18.1 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,434 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 89.4 kB in 11s (7,694 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please show the entire output of your `rvm install 2.0.0` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are irrelevant to you installing ruby - you have some broken dependencies (whatever the PPA for mixxx/mixxx is). Remove it from your software sources, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here (worked for me in mint), have to make sure to do sudo apt-get install checkinstall and all

https://gist.github.com/ngauthier/5039249

See also:

[Installing Ruby 2.0.0](http://www.jeffduckett.com/blog/530d336962756c47ee000000/installing-ruby-2-0-0.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that is installing without RVM. I am using RVM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108673/installing-ruby-2-0-0-using-rvm

does that work? otherwise it may or may not be possible via rvm