# trying to update rvm to get more recent ruby versions but not seeming to update

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am having a problem updating rvm.

Based upon [Update RVM list known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650164/update-rvm-list-known), I do:

```
Tue Apr 02$ rvm -v

rvm 1.8.1 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Tue Apr 02$ rvm get stable
Tue Apr 02$ rvm -v

rvm 1.8.1 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

But it seems like the rvm version should be updating. What is the proper command to get it it to update and to update `rvm list known` which stays the same after `rvm get stable`. How would I update rvm to get more recent rubies that I can upgrate to?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable
```

Comment: thx, I ran `rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p290 1.9.3-p392` and it asked me to `Are you sure you wish to MOVE gems from ruby-1.9.2-p290 to ruby-1.9.3-p392?` I said yes and this step has been going on for 45 minutes. Is this normal? it's `Moving gemsets...
Moving ruby-1.9.2-p290 to ruby-1.9.3-p392
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p392 pristine.`

Comment: I wouldn't have moved the gems. Try without moving them. You can install them later as needed.