# How to know the lastest version of ruby in Terminal?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I intend to install ruby by rvm to my Macbook Pro, with the command tutorial:

```
$ rvm requirements
$ rvm install 2.3.0
$ rvm use 2.3.0 --default
```

But you know the `2.3.0` maybe not the newest version, because the tutorial is long time ago.

So, how can I get the lastest version of ruby in command?

Comment: Do you actually want to install the latest version of RVM or do you want to use RVM to install the latest version of Ruby?

Comment: @Holger Just, yeah, i want `rvm install 2.3.0` the meaning, it is ruby version, alright?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650164/update-rvm-list-known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rvm get head # update list of known rubies. Necessary if your local list is out of date.
rvm install ruby --latest # install the latest ruby
```

The latest ruby version (at time of writing) is 2.4.0

Comment: I use `rvm get head`, terminal shows:`Downloading https://get.rvm.io
No GPG software exists to validate rvm-installer, skipping.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz`,and it takes a long time, is it normal ?

Comment: rvm uses GPG to verify the integrity of downloaded rubies. If you have gpg in your path (install varies by system) then that message should go away. I don't know why downloading master.tar.gz would take a while, however... It takes maybe 5 seconds for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can run `rvm list known` to see all options, but 2.3 is pretty new and will be a good choice.